# What exactly means the prefix value from Sails js controller configuration file?

Tags: express, sails.js

I was editing the values from the controller config file in my Sails js project. I don't know or exactly understand what is the meaning of the prefix attribute. Will this attribute add a prefix to my routes (e.g. 'post /users' will become 'post /prefix/users') or it will be appended to file path to the controller? (i.e. api/prefix/controllers/ && api/prefix/models/)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will add a prefix to your routes. So for example if you wanted to create a versioned API instead of manually binding all of your routes in the `config/routes.js` file you could simply add `/api/v1` to the prefix config and now the Blueprints would work with routes like `/api/v1/user/1`.

It won't change the file paths at all only the bound routes.

Comment: Hello again. I've edited the prefix attribute to 'api/v1' and in my routes I have 'post /users': {controller: Users, action: create} . When I POST to /api/v1/users the router dispatches to UsersController Index action. If I post to /users everything works as expected. Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong? thanks.